# Detecting faulty handlebar/spacebar tags in texteditor : MeteorJS

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I want the user to be able to write handlebar tags in a text editor like `{{username}}` which will be saved in the database to be rendered later in the server using server-side rendering.

However, I want to add a client-side check to see if there is any faulty handlebar tags like `{{username}` or `{username}}` or `{{username` or `username}}`

I tried using `Blaze.renderWithData()`, but it didn't throw any error and just rendered the values as is.

Is there a way to detect faulty tags?

Thanks.

Comment: You could try `Blaze.toHtml` - http://blazejs.org/api/blaze.html#Blaze-toHTML

Comment: Another way would be to provide a list / autocomplete of all supported tags and just take their code as it is. Either it creates an error / renders wrong or not.